# Calling Function of parent from component included in container Ref

Tags: angular

I Have a component1 in which i have included a component2 using viewContainerRef. There is function `closeSideBar()` defined in component1 and i want to call that from component2.
I have tried Event Emitter and various other methods by searching here but nothing works for me.
How can i accomplish that ?

Comment: you can use @ViewChild to inherit all member properties & functions of another component.

Comment: @AlokMali Can you please elaborate more by some example ?

Comment: Show the HTML code

Comment: Sure, I will provide you an example soon.

Comment: I have posted an answer if you want more clarification I will add both of my components here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import 'viewChild' and 'component1' in component2.

```
 import { ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
```

CityComponent is component1 in my case.

```
  import { CityComponent } from "../city/city.component";
```

Insert below the line in the class declaration

```
  @ViewChild(CityComponent) cityComp;
```

where cityComp is an alias.

and you can access or change the child component's property. just like.

```
  this.cityComp.city = -1; 
  this.cityComp.citiesddl = [];
```